# Connect 1/4“ supply line to 3/8” outer diameter faucet line

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

The 3/8 " end of the 1/2" to 3/8 " faucet connector neither fits a 3/8" pipe nor a 1/4" pipe. Right now I have to find a connector which connects the 3/8" end of the faucet connector to 1/4" pipe. Which connector should I be looking for ?

[image]

Comment: The are compression fitting threads, not pipe threads. And what awful galvanic corrosion horror-show are you building there with black iron pipe connected to copper pipe in water service??? You ***will*** come to regret that...

Comment: It is much simpler to stay with all 1/2" pipe (or larger if needed) . I had a free box of fittings with 3/8, 1/4 and maybe even 1/8 ; I basically never used them.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what I am doing clearly :) But after spending 900 $ to get one pressure reducer valve replaced, the thought of calling a plumber to get this tub fitted makes me question my life. Any suggestions are appreciated. Ofcourse this platform won't let me compensate for advice, I would if I could.

Comment: Free lesson number 1 - black iron pipe is not suitable for potable water service, (it's a code violation, actually) nor sensible for ANY water service. Galvanized at minimum, stainless for a lot less trouble and no lead, or just skip threaded pipe altogether because it is 2020 and there's PEX, which ain't butyl. If your area is under IPC rules, read this: https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018/effective-use-of-the-international-plumbing-code and it will help keep you on track, but reading it won't make you a plumber - it might make you a better DIY, though.

Comment: Ok, thankyou for the suggestions. I will follow the suggestions in answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoa... remove everything you just installed, including those valves.

- the valves you used have *garden hose thread* outlets, and you have incorrectly screwed *pipe thread* fittings to them. It **will** leak, if not now then in the future. Those valves are commonly used to supply clothes washing machines which use supply lines with *garden hose thread*.

Replace the valves with *dual-outlet angle stop* valves, which come with the proper 1/2" pipe thread inlet **and** outlets that will fit your *3/8" compression thread* flex supply **and** your *1/2" pipe thread* flex supply:

[image]

Don't use those black iron fittings; they will corrode. You won't need them anyway if you purchase the correct stop-valves.

Comment: Thankyou Sir, I will try this. I will leave this open for a few days until I get the parts and complete fixing it so I can ask questions if I have any. I will mark this answered once I'm done. I hope thats okay.

Comment: So far unable to find one that is not made in China. I'll keep looking. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, another option is to buy a domestic 1/2" ips dual outlet valve, then convert one side to 3/8" comp. thread using a thread-on adapter.